# Cheerio not finding table content

Tags: cheerio, nw.js

I need to parse an HTML containg a table.

```
<div>
<table id="tableID">
    <tr>
        <td class="tdClass">
            <span id="id1">Some data i need to access</span>
        </td>
        <td class="tdClass">
            <span id="id2">Some data i need to access</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I'm using cheerio on a NW.js app. I  can't figure out how to access the datas, I've tried with span's ids, but it doesn't work.

The div is contained in the body of the page.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html)
alert($('#id1').html())
```

I'm getting null when I'm trying to alert the content of the span.

Comment: please also post your js code

Comment: Updated my post with my js code.

Comment: are you running this server-side or client side? i haven't  used NW.js, but in node.js you cant use alert, your code works fine in jsbin: https://jsbin.com/nibanayoma/edit?html,js,output

Comment: On the exact same code, I'm getting a null. That's very strange. I tried my complete html on jsbin, and it works. I'm lost :(

Comment: where are you geting your html from could you post that too?

Comment: alright, I read too fast, you're using jQuery while I'm using cheerio.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ = cheerio.load(html, {normalizeWhitespace: false, xmlMode: true});
```